# How can I create a data frame when I only have the values for each cell (possibly more than one string per cell) and their column and row index?

Tags: r, dataframe, indices, data-handling

I have a dataframe including the values for each cell (possibly more than one value) and the row and the column index.

```
df = data.frame(values = c(1,"Sven", 20,"Mueller","sept",2,30,"John","Mar","Hynes","Marc"), 
                colI = c(1,2,3,2,4,1,3,2,4,2,2), rowI = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2))
```

And I want to get something similar to the following data.frame:

```
df_final= data.frame(Index = c(1,2), name = c("Sven, Mueller", "John, Hynes, Marc"), age = c(20,30), 
                     month = c("sept","Mar"))
```

However, I haven't been able to do anything and I have also not found a solution online. I am not able to find a solution to bring the values to their corresponding place in the dataframe and I think that it is even a bigger challenge that the cells can contain a different amount of values.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The sample code for `df` throws an error `[...] differing number of rows: 11, 10`. Please double-check.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add a 2 to the sample rowI

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, you can first `aggregate` your data to one comma separated string for each row and column index and then use `unstack`.

```
temp <- aggregate(values~colI + rowI, df, toString)
unstack(temp, values~colI)

#  X1                X2 X3   X4
#1  1     Sven, Mueller 20 sept
#2  2 John, Hynes, Marc 30  Mar
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(values = c("1", "Sven", "20", "Mueller", "sept", 
"2", "30", "John", "Mar", "Hynes", "Marc"), colI = c(1, 2, 3, 
2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2), rowI = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: That's way more easy than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `stringr`, all included in `tidyverse`:

```r
df %>%
# bring your data into a wider format
  pivot_wider(id_cols=rowI, names_from=colI, values_from=values, values_fn=list) %>% 
# remove the nested listing
  unnest(everything()) %>%
# rename the columns
  select(Index = rowI, name=`2`, age=`3`, month=`4`) %>%
# group all rows based on the index
  group_by(Index) %>%
# concatenate the name column
  mutate(name=str_c(name, collapse=", ")) %>%
# remove duplicates
  distinct()
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Index [2]
  Index name              age   month
  <dbl> <chr>             <chr> <chr>
1     1 Sven, Mueller     20    sept 
2     2 John, Hynes, Marc 30    Mar
```

Note: I changed your input data a little bit and added a single `2` to your `rowI` column (see Maurits Evers' comment).

Comment: Thanks Ronak and Martin for your help. The "easy" solution perfectly solves my question.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(rowI, names_from = colI, values_from = values, values_fn = toString) %>% 
  select(-rowI) %>% 
  purrr::set_names(c("ID", "name", "age", "month"))
```